# Ubuntu Network Speed issue

Tags: networking, 20.04, sudo, users, download-speed

I am new to the Ubuntu operating system (20.04 LTS) and I have no knowledge of ubuntu whatsoever.

Last week I started my first job and received the laptop HP Probook 440 g8 with Ubuntu operating system. Now here is the problem:

I connect to my wifi but the speed is really slow (around 1-2 Mbps) but the same wifi is working pretty well on other devices like my personal laptop (Windows-10 with speed around 20 Mbps minimum), my phone as well. Now I searched up Online and understood to switch off the power management. But I don't have admin rights (root/sudo rights...whatever that is). Only user rights I have.

Now I call up my organization about this but they can't give me the admin password & said me to come to the office to resolve this (I work from home). So I want to know is there any i can resolve this issue or make my organization resolve it from home.

Working with 1Mbps speed really is terrible!!

PS: The IT people at my office are not supportive so yeah I need help guys :/

Thank You

Comment: The problem is likely in your own AP regardless of other devices working fine. If it was the case that changes had to be done on that laptop specifically we wouldn't be able to help you either since it's managed by your organization.

Comment: Hi Siddarth, congrats on your first job, I hope you will enjoy working with Ubuntu. This sound like a driver issue, which your system administrators will need to solve. Remember - they're actually employed to do that. ;-) For now you could try if flipping the WiFi power saving switch helps. This is in the Power page in the Settings. There is a switch marked "WiFi can be turned off to save power". Not sure it will help, but worth a try.

Comment: @zwets You are suggesting me to switch off wifi. Which is not the problem. The wifi speed is the problem. Please go through my question once again.

Comment: @SiddarthKumarJha Ah yes my bad, I thought the switch enabled power-saving mode (allowing the device to go to low power modes intermittently). If it actually just switches it off, that doesn't really help.